# Sublime - Keyboard shortcut to go to first selection of 'Find in Files'

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

When I search in Sublime Text using 'Find in Files' for a keyword, I always have to use my mouse to click the selection I want to go to in that file. Is there any way I can use my keyboard to make the selection jump instead? Or if there's any plugins that do this?

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you want to be able to hit e.g. `enter` on a search instead of using the mouse to open it, that you want to use the keyboard to skip between the matched lines (possibly in addition to the above) or that you want a keyboard shortcut to navigate through the results? If it's the latter, `Find > Find Results > Next Result` in the menu (or the key bound to it, visible there) will let you navigate through the results directly without having to interact with the result panel at all.

Comment: @OdatNurd I guess I'd like to use the keyboard to jump to a selection's location in the file (which is 1 + 2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default you can navigate between all of the results of a find operation by using the menu items in `Find > Find Results` or their associated key bindings (visible in the menu). Doing that, the results go in order forward or backward, which may or may not be desirable if there are many results.

There aren't any navigation keys for jumping around inside the find in files output apart from the usual file navigation, but you can add such with a plugin:

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class JumpToFindMatchCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    """
    In a find in files result, skip the cursor to the next or previous find
    match, based on the location of the first cursor in the view.
    """
    def run(self, edit, forward=True):
        # Find the location of all matches and specify the one to navigate to
        # if there aren't any in the location of travel.
        matches = self.view.find_by_selector("constant.numeric.line-number.match")
        fallback = matches[0] if forward else matches[-1]

        # Get the position of the first caret.
        cur = self.view.sel()[0].begin()

        # Navigate the found locations and focus the first one that comes
        # before or after the cursor location, if any.
        pick = lambda p: (cur < p.begin()) if forward else (cur > p.begin())
        for pos in matches if forward else reversed(matches):
            if pick(pos):
                return self.focus(pos)

        # not found; Focus the fallback location.
        self.focus(fallback)

    def focus(self, location):
            # Focus the found location in the window
            self.view.show(location, True)

            # Set the cursor to that location.
            self.view.sel().clear()
            self.view.sel().add(location.begin())
```

This implements a new command `jump_to_find_match` that takes an optional argument of `forward` to determine if the jump should be forward or backward, and will focus the view on the next or previous find result based on the cursor location of the first cursor in the file, wrapping as needed.

In combination with this plugin, key bindings such as the following can be set up to use the command. Here we're using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> keys; the `context` in each ensures that the binding is only active while in find results.

```json
{
    "keys": ["tab"],
    "command": "jump_to_find_match",
    "args": {
        "forward": true
    },
    "context": [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.find-in-files", "match_all": true },
    ],
},

{
    "keys": ["shift+tab"],
    "command": "jump_to_find_match",
    "args": {
        "forward": false
    },
    "context": [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.find-in-files", "match_all": true },
    ],
},
```

That will allow you to navigate between the matches in the find panel, but you would still have to use the mouse in order to actually jump to the match location in the related file.

To do that by keyboard, you can use [this plugin](https://github.com/STealthy-and-haSTy/SublimeScraps/blob/master/plugins/double_click.py), which implements a command that simulates a double click at the location of the cursor. A key binding such as the following triggers the command in response to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, as long as the cursor is on a find match:

```json
{
    "keys": ["enter"],
    "command": "double_click_at_caret",
    "context": [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.find-in-files", "match_all": true },
    ],
},
```

Comment: Wow, this is really comprehensive. Thanks @OdatNurd!

Comment: can I ask where I would put `double_click.py` in my sublime installation to be able to use it?

Comment: You should put that plugin as well as the one above in your `User` package; you can find where that is by using `Preferences > Browse Packages...` from the menu or the command palette.

Comment: Appreciate it, your commands works smoothly! I'd give you more +1's if I could :)

Comment: I gotta say, even 3 years later, these commands make finding snippets in sublime a pleasure :)

Comment: Works smoothly!

Answer (score 2):

`F4` is the answer you are looking for. `Shift+F4` searches backwards. Corresponding `next_result` and `prev_result` are part of default keybinding.

```
    { "keys": ["f4"], "command": "next_result" },
    { "keys": ["shift+f4"], "command": "prev_result" },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `Use buffer` button to open the results in a new tab.